How to bind custom functions to vuetify stepper's prev and next buttons
I'm trying to setup a login process in vuetify where in the 1st step, you enter your e-mail-address, in the 2nd, you enter your password and in the 3rd, you enter TOTP information for a 2nd-factor check.
For this, after any step, I want to have a custom function that sends a request to the server and only continues (moves to the next step, if I get a valid response.
(step 1: checking if the e-mail exists, step 2: checking if the password is correct, step 3: checking if the TOTP token is correct)
But I do not get custom functions bound to my stepper action buttons.
This is my code, stripped down to the bare minimum:
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card>
      <v-stepper
        v-model="step"
        :items="items"
        @click:prev="prev"
        @click:next="next"
      >
        <template v-slot:item.1>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item.2>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item.3>
        </template>
      </v-stepper>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const step = ref(0);

const items = [
  { title: 'E-Mail' },
  { title: 'Password' },
  { title: '2nd-Factor' },
];

const prev = () => {
  console.log('clicked prev')
  
  # prev step
}
const next = () => {
  console.log('clicked next')

  # background call

  if(# error) {
    # error handling
  }

  # success handling (next step)
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="sass">

</style>

But the prev and next functions are not triggered when clicking the buttons in the stepper action menu.
Note that I used TS instead of plain JS.

click:prev and click:next are events emitted by v-stepper-actions component, not by v-stepper.

@IgorMoraru the problem is, whenever I include v-stepper-actions, it produces a second row of buttons, that do not effect the stepper in any way (except for the visual appearance) I used @click="next" but there was no "clicked next" in the console

Check the example code in the documentation that uses v-stepper-actions and next/prev click events.  It looks like you need to use the default template and define all 3 of the stepper header, window, and actions

Check documentation provided by @yoduh above, and do something like this:
Template
<v-stepper-actions
      :disabled="disabled"
      @click:next="customNext(next)"
      @click:prev="prev"
    ></v-stepper-actions>

JS
methods: {
  customNext(next) {
    alert('custom next function')
    console.log('custom next function')
    next()
  },
},

Check this sample

You can use v-model step with custom action like this;
`<v-stepper :items="items" v-model="step" hide-actions >
  <template v-slot:item.1 >
   foo
  </template>

    <template v-slot:item.2>
      <v-card title="Step Two" flat>...</v-card>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.3>
      <v-card title="Step Three" flat>...</v-card>
    </template>

      <v-stepper-actions
          :disabled="false"
          :next-text="step>1?'finish':'next'"
          :prev-text="step>1?'back':''"
          @click:next="step=step+1"
          @click:prev="step=step-1"
        ></v-stepper-actions>
  </v-stepper>
<script setup>
let step = ref(1);
const items=ref(['test1', 'head2', 'foo3'])
</script>
`

Maybe you do not need any additional function for next...etc...
